# regular expression matching in java without using regex

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I recently got an interview question where I needed to implement regular expression matching in Java without using regex matching.

> Given an input string (s) and a pattern (p), implement regular
>   expression matching with support for '.', '+', '*' and '?'.

---

```
// (pattern, match) --> bool does it match
// operators:
// . --> any char
// + --> 1 or more of prev char
// * --> 0 or more of prev char
// ? --> 0 or 1 of prev char

// (abc+c, abcccc) --> True
// (abcd*, abc) --> True
// (abc?c, abc) --> True
// (abc.*, abcsdfsf) --> True
```

I came up with below code which only implements '.' and '*' but not able to figure out how to implement others:

```
  public static boolean isMatch(String s, String p) {
    if (p.length() == 0) {
      return s.length() == 0;
    }
    if (p.length() > 1 && p.charAt(1) == '*') { // second char is '*'
      if (isMatch(s, p.substring(2))) {
        return true;
      }
      if (s.length() > 0 && (p.charAt(0) == '.' || s.charAt(0) == p.charAt(0))) {
        return isMatch(s.substring(1), p);
      }
      return false;
    } else { // second char is not '*'
      if (s.length() > 0 && (p.charAt(0) == '.' || s.charAt(0) == p.charAt(0))) {
        return isMatch(s.substring(1), p.substring(1));
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Also what is the best way to implement this problem?

Comment: Frequently regular expressions are implemented with (variants of a) *tagged dfa's* https://github.com/samrushing/irken-tdfa

Comment: In an hour long interview, a recursive matcher is undoubtedly the expected solution (after discussing what a terrible idea this would be in a production system). You could trivially implement `x+` using your existing code by just rewriting and matching `xx*`, and `x?etc` by checking `xetc` || `etc`.

Comment: Backtracking becomes a problem if you're expected to match the "longest leftmost" rule that most implementations support. For example, given `"abcdefxwvutsrqx"`, should `"ab.*x"` match the entire string? If so, then `".*"` means you always have to scan the entire string to find the last `'x'` character.

Comment: @JimMischel If it just returns a bool, then you don't need to worry about which match.  That makes it easier.  Though you can still code disastrous regexes.

Comment: Relevant: the dynamic programming solution, eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572289/understanding-regex-string-matching-using-dynamic-programming

Answer (score 0):

Here is untested code.  The idea is that we keep track of where we are in the string and the pattern.  This would NOT be a good approach to try to extend to a full RE engine (just consider what adding parentheses would take), but is fine for this case:

```
public static boolean isMatch (String p, String s, int pos_p, int pos_s) {
    if (pos_p == p.length()) {
        // We matched the whole pattern.
        return true;
    }
    else if (pos_s == s.length()) {
        // We reached the end of the string without matching.
        return false;
    }
    else if (pos_p == -1) {
        // Do we match the pattern starting next position?
        if (isMatch(p, s, pos_p + 1, pos_s + 1)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            // Try to match the pattern starting later.
            return isMatch(p, s, pos_p, pos_s + 1);
        }
    }
    else {
        char thisCharP = p.charAt(pos_p);
        char nextCharP = pos_p + 1 < p.length() ? p.charAt(pos_p + 1) : 'x';

        // Does this character match at this position?
        boolean thisMatch = (thisCharP == s.charAt(pos_s));
        if (thisCharP == '.') {
            thisMatch = true;
        }

        if (nextCharP == '*') {
            // Try matching no times - we don't need thisMatch to be true!
            if (isMatch(p, s, pos_p + 2, pos_s)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                // Try matching 1+ times, now thisMatch is required.
                return thisMatch && isMatch(p, s, pos_p, pos_s + 1);
            }
        }
        else if (nextCharP == '+') {
            if (! thisMatch) {
                // to match 1+, we have to match here.
                return false;
            }
            else if (isMatch(p, s, pos_p + 2, pos_s + 1)) {
                // We matched once.
                return true;
            }
            else {
                // Can we match 2+?
                return isMatch(p, s, pos_p, pos_s + 1);
            }
        }
        else if (thisMatch) {
            // Can we match the rest of the pattern?
            return isMatch(p, s, pos_p + 1, pos_s + 1);
        }
        else {
            // We didn't match here, this is a fail.
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isMatch (String p, String s) {
    // Can we match starting anywhere?
    return isMatch(p, s, -1, -1);
}
```